# Android GPS Device not responding

Tags: android

I have a working code to get the current location using GPS. However it stopped working suddenly. On further debugging using GpsStatusListner, I noticed Satellite count is always 0 (before it used to show upto 8/9 sats).

And other navigation software (google navigator, At&t navigator) none of them are able to get fix on GPS.

Is there a way to reset/reccaliberate the GPS component in my phone? I tried disabling/enabling GPS/Network under Location settings and rebooted the phone multiple times :(

Device: HTC Inspire.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok many had this problem

1. Make sure gps is disabled
2. Go to the market
3. Download "Fast Reboot"
4. Run it
5. Run navigation (when it's done)
6. It'll ask you to show location settings
7. Click okay
8. Enable gps
9. Open navigation again

it should work

Comment: I did system update and seems it has fixed the issue for now. If it happens again I'll try your method. Thank you for sharing!